# mock axios request jest network error

Tags: unit-testing, redux, jestjs, axios

I am trying to create async tests with axios-mock and jest.

This is my test file:

```
var axios = require('axios');
var MockAdapter = require('axios-mock-adapter');

const middlewares = [thunk,axiosMiddleware]
const mockStore = configureMockStore(middlewares)

describe('async-actions', () => {

    var instance;
    var mock;

    beforeEach(function() {
         instance = axios.create();
         mock = new MockAdapter(instance);
    });

    afterEach(() => {
        mock.reset()
        mock.restore()
    })

    it('creates FETCH_BOOKINGS_SUCCESS when fetch bookings has been done', () => {

     mock
          .onGet('/bookings').reply(200, {
             data: [
                 { id: 1, name: 'test booking' }
             ]
         });

        const expectedActions = [
            {type: "FETCH_BOOKINGS_START" },
            {type: "FETCH_BOOKINGS_SUCCESS", }
        ]

        const store = mockStore({
            session: {
                token: {
                    token: "test_token"
                }
            }
        })

        return store.dispatch(actions.fetchBookingsTest())
            .then(
                () => {
                    expect(store.getActions()).toEqual(expectedActions)
                })


        // return of async actions
    })

})
```

And my action:

```
export function fetchBookingsTest() {
    return (dispatch) => {
        dispatch(async.fetchDataStart(namedType));
        return dispatch(rest.get(BOOKINGS))
            .then(
                (data) => {
                    dispatch(async.fetchDataSuccess(data,namedType));
                },
                (error) => {
                    dispatch(async.fetchDataFailure(error,namedType));
                }
            )
    }
}
```

I have middleware setup that uses the authentication token from the redux store for each get request. That is why I have setup "test_token" in the mock store.

When I run this test I receive the response

```
[{"type": "FETCH_BOOKINGS_START"}, {"payload": [Error: Network Error], "type": "FETCH_BOOKINGS_FAILURE"}]
```

Why am I getting a network error? Do i need to do more setup with Jest to avoid authentication with mock-axios?